# Would appending to a non existing element create a new instance of that element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

In my browser, I have a textbox and a submit button. Using the text from the textbox, I want to add that text as a list item at the end of an unordered list. The unordered list does not exist yet but I want the text to appear under the textbox and submit button. I made this function:

**Code:**

```
 function display(text) {                       // 'text' from the textbox
      $('ul').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
 }
```

When I use .display(), I want to be able to display the text in the parameter as a new list item in an unordered list.

**Question:** Does JQuery create a new 'ul' if one doesn't exist yet or should I create one first? If so, am I using JQuery correctly to add a list item to the unordered list?

Any advice helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must use `$('<ul>')` to create a new `<ul>`, while `$('ul')` select the already existed element.

For more information, see [`jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Then you can rewrite you code like this:

```
var ul = $('<ul>');  // save the new created element.
ul.appendTo('body')  // add it into <body> or other place you want to insert
function display(text) {                       // 'text' from the textbox
      ul.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
 }
```

Comment: You're creating the `<ul>` element, but not inserting it into the DOM. So this code won't do anything. You need to insert it in the DOM. Of course the question is where to insert it.

Comment: Ah, that is funny timing. Just as I posted my comment, you updated your answer to insert the element into the DOM. :-)

Comment: @MichaelGeary yes it is a coincidence :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('ul')` selector creates a jQuery array containing every `<ul>` element on your page. If there are no `<ul>` elements, the array is empty. If you want a `<ul>` element and there isn't one, you need to create it yourself, which of course you can easily do with jQuery.

The way you're appending the `<li>` element is fine, but it won't do anything if there is not a `<ul>` on the page.

Also you really shouldn't be selecting by tagname like this. What if there is more than one `<ul>` on the page? You should select it by id or class.